# Method overloads object and unspecified type

Tags: c#

I have the following method with an overload:

```
public string GetName(object obj)
{
    return obj.ToString();
}

public string GetName(CustomClass cc)
{
    return cc.Name + " - " + cc.Description;
}
```

Now if I call the method with an untyped IEnumerable wich holds CustomClass the GetName(object obj) gets called, to fix this I have modified the method like this:

```
public string GetName(object obj)
{
    if (obj is CustomClass)
        return GetName(obj as CustomClass);

    return obj.ToString();
}
```

I think its rather annoying to write 20 IF statements and catch all the other possibilities, is there an easier way to call the correct overload with an untyped IEnumerable enumeration?

Here is the code that calls the GetName(object obj):

```
IEnumerable rawData = GetData(); //DataBase method that fetches a CustomClass

foreach (var rawDataItem in rawData)
{
    Debug.Print(GetName(rawDataItem)); //calls the GetName(object obj) overload
}
```

Pls dont tell me to override ToString from my CustomClass, help me fix this method calling problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you *could* use [dynamic typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). That will basically defer overload resolution until execution time:

```
foreach (dynamic rawDataItem in rawData)
{
    Debug.Print(GetName(rawDataItem));
}
```

Note that there's potentially a performance cost here - it may well be minimal and insignificant, but it's worth being aware of.

EDIT: To handle the recursion side of things, you'd probably want two different names, e.g. `GetName` and `GetNameImpl` where `GetName` delegates to `GetNameImpl` which is what all the useful overloads are called. So you'd have:

```
// Note that dynamic as a parameter type is equivalent to object for callers.
// The dynamic part is only relevant within the method.
public string GetName(dynamic obj)
{
    return GetNameImpl(obj);
}

// Fallback when no other overloads match
private string GetNameImpl(object obj)
{
    ...
}

private string GetNameImpl(IEnumerable obj)
{
    // Maybe build up the name by calling GetName on each element?
}
```

Note that there's a potential problem with this: if you have two overloads for different interfaces and one type implements both interfaces (but there isn't a specific overload for that type itself) then you'll get an exception at execution time.

If you want callers to be able to call the overloads directly, you could just rename the dynamic one to `GetNameDynamic` and the others to `GetName` for example (and make them public).

I rarely find that `dynamic` is a good solution, but it *would* avoid the code duplication. I would try to step back and find a different design to be honest. You explicitly rejected it in the question, but polymorphism *is* the preferred way of handling this. You don't need to necessarily override `ToString` - you could make all of the custom types implement a particular interface, and use that where it's available, for example.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: How would I use the dynamic inside the GetName(object obj) method, without calling the GetName(object obj) over and over again? So that it only works for overloads which arent the ...(object obj)?

Answer (score 1):

```
return GetName((dynamic)obj);
```

will postpone overload resolution till runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Without dynamic typing, the classic OOP solution to supporting [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) (where the method called depends on both the concrete type of the object having the method and the concrete type of the passed object) is the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public string GetName(object obj)
{
    if (!(obj is IEnumerable<object>))
        return GetName(obj as CustomClass);

    return obj.ToString();
}
```